# PHP If user logged in not working first refresh

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have a pretty simple function, it checks to see if ['id'] exists in the session and redirects if that's the case, located on the top of my login.php
It works, but only after I submit the login form twice.

require_once 'inc/header.inc';

which contains before html:

```
<?php
require 'inc/init.php';
session_regenerate_id();
 ?>
```

init.php contains

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION) || empty($_SESION) ){
    require 'inc/db.php';
    require 'users.class.php';
    require 'general.class.php';
    require 'functions.php';
    $users      = new Users($db);
    $general    = new General($db);
    $errors     = array();
}

?>
```

This is the top of my login.php :

```
 <?php
 require_once 'inc/header.inc';

 if ($general->is_logged_in()) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
```

Yet the page keeps on loadin the first time.

The function if you care for it:

```
public function is_logged_in() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use .inc for includes, use .php like anywhere else. Or make sure to have properly set up .htaccess, but still, it's a bad practice. (unrelated to your problem but worth mentioning)

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['id']`?

Comment: Typo? Change `empty($_SESION)` to `empty($_SESSION)`

Comment: Plus, you may want to use `if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['id']) ){` instead.

Comment: @ Fred- I use init.php in all my pages, I'd still want my classes loading if I wasn't logged in.
@Babal - It's the return value from my login.php. It's definitely set. Anyway, I added a redirect after the return. Not sure if just covering up a problem or I should have it there.

Comment: Did you fix the typo in `empty($_SESION)`?

Comment: Plus, `session_start();` needs to be inside all files which are not calling it already.

Comment: I did now, thanks Fred.
Init.php is in my header, which is in all pages, with session_start() - isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0):

don't you think it should be like this

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

as in your function the id is generated first and then session is started as a result of which the values is not assigned to session.

Comment: Are you sure? init.php contains my start, and regenid comes after.

Comment: oh.. then it is right.. and yes the function session_generate_id() on very page load generate a new id and the previous id is overwritten. You can check here.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Just added redirect after return/setid from login(), rather than relying on checking if id exists at page load and runnin the redirect on page load - user can then not re-enter the page in any case. Not sure why the former wouldn't work.